# Python: using strings to access dictionary values

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am writing the following json to a file like so:

```
with open('/etc/data_file.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump({"account":{"id":10,"user_id":10}}, f)
```

I know the write is successfull because I can read and print the file:

```
with open('/etc/data_file.json') as json_file:
  json_data = json.load(json_file)    
print json_data
>>> {"account":{"id":10,"user_id":10}}
```

But if I try to access one of the keys then I get the following error message:

```
  print json_data["account"]
  >>> TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I don't get it. I want hash/dict behaviour, and this is what I would expect from an array/list. I'm very new to python, coming from ruby so this is really strange for me.

Comment: You have your `data_file.json` where? `etc`? Why? That too writable?

Comment: I actually seem to be getting this code to work fine. Are you sure there is no other code between your lines that is re-writing the var `json_data`? It looks like json_data is a str object rather than a dict object based on the error you are getting, but it is not clear to me why. Can you try a `print type(json_data)` statement immediately after you do your `json_data = json.load(json_file)` line?

Comment: Your code should work fine as long _as long as the write is successful_. If the file is already there and contains a string version of the dict, and the write is failing you would get the error you are seeing. It might help to `print repr(json_data)` Otherwise you can't see if it's a dict or a string masquerading as a dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reproduced code-execution does not indicate an issue on "using strings to access dictonary values":

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> import json
>>> with open( 'data_file.json', 'w' ) as f:
...    json.dump( { "account": { "id": 10, "user_id": 10 } }, f )
...
>>> with open( 'data_file.json' ) as json_file:
...    json_data = json.load( json_file )
...
>>> print json_data
{u'account': {u'user_id': 10, u'id': 10}}
>>>
>>> print json_data[u'account']
{u'user_id': 10, u'id': 10}
>>> print json_data["account"]
{u'user_id': 10, u'id': 10}
>>>
```

Comment: How is it helpful to regurgitate the code from the question in to an answer with no explanation or exposition?  "Works for me" is not an answer.

Comment: If you couldn't construct a viable answer given the input, then the proper avenue to request clarification is the comments.  This answer doesn't add anything to anyone trying to seek an answer to this question.

Comment: @user3666197 Downvote because this isn't an answer and is better suited as a comment to the question.

Comment: Thanks for expressed opinions. Question was being asked on **"using strings to access dictionary values"**, which IMHO was answered by re-testing both plain-string and unicode-prefix-ed string to prove, the python using strings to access dictionary values indeed works as being asked ( that for the StackOverflow principle "answer a given question" ). The rest is not an issue that was asked ( that would be a base for future find/search engine results ) but a trouble with fileIO collisions, that (may) introduce a defect, that may skew the original post-ers experience, but not with the string/dict

Comment: The question is about fixing the OP's problem.  If the title is bad, submit an edit to the question to fix it.  Answering a question that is irrelevant to the body of the question is not helpful.